# Wordpress with Bones starter theme: Embed existing JavaScript for text limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I need a script for limiting the wordpress excerpt textarea. When users writing posts they are not allowed to type in more than a specified amount of letters. I found a script that fits my needs, but I tried to get it working with my theme for hours: http://docs.wedevs.com/docs/wp-user-frontend-pro/tutorials/limiting-character-in-text-input-textarea/

With Bones there is a file "scripts.js", from which you call the function. I tried to split the code to limittextarea.js (function) and call it in scripts.js.

Every time I start to type in letters FireFox Debugger tells me:
"ReferenceError: limitText is not defined"

limittextarea.js:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.limitText = function (field, maxChar){
    var ref = $(field),
    val = ref.val();

        if ( val.length >= maxChar ) {
             ref.val(val.substr(0, maxChar));
         }
}

})(jQuery);
```

scripts.js:

```
$('#excerpt').on('keyup', function() {
     limitText(this, 10)
});
```

I know - this is really for beginners, but could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced with JS and just recently had a problem similar to yours with the file not being loaded in time because wordpress likes js to be done a specific way. You can read more on WP Enque_script [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) 
Instead of editing the bones theme directly why not make your text limit a plugin?  Then you can call your limittextarea.js from the custom plugin.

So you would make a custom plugin which is very simple.
1.  Just add a new folder in your plugins folder.
2.  Name it what you want it.  In this example I have it named. "text-limit-plugin". 
3.  Create a folder inside that plugin folder called "js" and stick your limittextarea.js in that folder. 
4.  Then create a new php file in your code editor of choice and save it in your text-limit-plugin folder and name it text-limit-plugin.php.
5.  Next add this to the top.

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: text-limit-plugin
* Plugin URI: "your dev site url here"
* Description: A Plugin to limit Text
* Version: 1.0 or whatever version of the plugin (pretty self explanatory)
* Author: Plugin Author's Name
* Author URI: Author's website
* License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL12
*/
```

Next add this below the above code.

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
wp_register_script('text_limit_script', plugins_url('text-limit-plugin/js/limittextarea.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('text_limit_script');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );  
?>
```

You can also wrap your .js in a no conflict wrapper to make sure it doesn't conflict with script.js. bys placing this before your function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

Try doing it this way and see if this fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for helping me! I created a new file admin_scripts.js and put in the whole code. All other things I tried didn't work.

Comment: No problem.  If it's resolved go ahead and click the check to close the topic.